# Add a row to pandas dataframe based on dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is my example dataframe row:

```
A  B  C  D  E
```

I have a dictionary formatted like:

```
{'foo': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'bar': ['D', 'E']}
```

I would like to add a row above my original dataframe so my new dataframe is:

```
foo foo foo bar bar
 A   B   C   D   E
```

I think maybe the df.map function should be able to do it, but I've tried it and can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want set columns names by row of `DataFrame` with `dict` and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {'foo': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'bar': ['D', 'E']}
#swap keys with values
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'E': 'bar', 'A': 'foo', 'D': 'bar', 'B': 'foo', 'C': 'foo'}

df = pd.DataFrame([list('ABCDE')])
df.columns = df.iloc[0].map(d1).values
print (df)
  foo foo foo bar bar
0   A   B   C   D   E
```

If need set first row in one row `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list('ABCDE')])
df.loc[-1] = df.iloc[0].map(d1)
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4
0  foo  foo  foo  bar  bar
1    A    B    C    D    E
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of the second part - "set first row in one row"? I'm clearly missing something because I'm not getting an error, but my "foo bar" row is also not being added.

Comment: @Liquidity - There is my problem I dont 100% understand what need. So you need set columns names like first part of answer?

Comment: A top row is fine, they don't have to be column names. Just a first row that uses the dictionary to add a value above the top row of the original dataframe. What I'm getting now are the top two rows with NaN values.

Comment: @Liquidity - If get `NaN`s it means there is no match between values of row and values of dict.

Comment: I can manually compare and see that my dictionary matches the row, could there be an issue with quotes? That is, in the dictionary the key is 'A' but the row is just A.

Comment: @Liquidity - It is possible, or some whitepaces? Without real data hard to answer.

Comment: I'll keep playing with it. Your answer got me closer than I was before, thanks!